# Wallet development and custom configuration

Tags: account-to-account

I was referred here by some devs in my telegram group associated with freewallet.io when I was asking about custom wallet features.  Can you please provide me info on any feature that would allow me to accumulate BTC in a single wallet and then once that wallet receives a set amount of bitcoin, can then disperse the lump accumulation through a network of wallets on a schedule?  The goal would be to make this transparent to all parties involved and to function almost in a self sufficient manner.  The project would allow members to receive 25% of the allocation into their chosen wallet while returning the other 75% in a separate wallet that would be reinvested into the project.  Can I customize a wallet based on these requirements and functionalities?  Does something already pre exist?  Any info would be helpful!  Thank you so much!

Chris Clark

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.